# Save multiple HTML bodies as one using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have a string containing multiple `<html><body><div>Content</div></body></html>` Tags. I want to get all Contents an join them to one valid Structure. For example:

```
<html><body><div>Content</div></body></html>
<html><body><div>Content</div></body></html>
<html><body><div>Content</div></body></html>
```

Should be:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
        <div>Content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My current Code looks like this:

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $newDom = new DOMDocument();

    $newBody = "";

    $newDom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

    $bodyTags = $newDom->getElementsByTagName("body");

    foreach($bodyTags as $body) {
        $newBody .= $newDom->saveHTML($body);
    }
```

`$newBody` now contains all body Tags:

```
<body><div>Content</div></body>
<body><div>Content</div></body>
<body><div>Content</div></body>
```

How can I only save the HTML Content of each body Tag in `$newBody`?

**Edit:**

Based on @NigelRen s Answer this is my Solution:

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $newDom = new DOMDocument();

    $newBody = '';
    $newDom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

    $bodyTags = $newDom->getElementsByTagName("body");

    foreach($bodyTags as $body) {
        foreach ($body->childNodes as $node)   {
            $newBody .= $newDom->saveHTML($node);
        }
    }

    $newDom = new DOMDocument();
    $newDom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($newBody, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    $newBody = $newDom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's awkward as when you use `loadHTML()` it will attempt to fix the HTML in your original document.  This creates a structure which isn't what you might think it is.

BUT, if you have a basic outline of the document, the following will copy the contents of the `<body>` tags to a new document (comments in code)...

```
$html = '<html><body><div>Content1</div></body></html>
<html><body><div>Content2</div></body></html>
<html><body><div>Content3</div></body></html>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$newDom = new DOMDocument();

// New document with final code
$newBody = new DOMDocument();

$newDom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

// Set up basic template for new doucument
$newBody->loadHTML("<html><body /></html>");
// Find where to add any new content
$addBody = $newBody->getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
// Find the existing content to add
$bodyTags = $newDom->getElementsByTagName("body");
foreach($bodyTags as $body) {
    // Add all of the contents of the <body> tag into the new document
    foreach ( $body->childNodes as $node )   {
        // Import the node to copy to the new document and add it in
        $addBody->appendChild($newBody->importNode($node, true));
    }
}
echo $newBody->saveHTML();
```

which gives...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>Content1</div><div>Content2</div><div>Content3</div></body></html>
```

The limitations are that any content outside of the `<body>` tags and any attributes of the `<body>` tag are not preserved.

Comment: Thanks, this code was very helpful. I edited my Question and posted my final Code. Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The idea that you want to load multiple html documents into a single DOM tree necessarily means you have malformed X/HTML. Working with that will be tricky, because the DOM parser will make some assumptions about what you meant here that won't necessarily be intuitive. HTML is a promiscuous language so this will take some maneuvering.

Here's the gist of it though. You take each `body` element, recursively walk its node list, and recreate each element into a new document.

Here's how I would do it:

```
class DOMExtended extends DOMDocument {
    public function walk(DOMNode $node, $skipParent = false) {
        if (!$skipParent) {
            yield $node;
        }
        if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            foreach ($node->childNodes as $n) {
                yield from $this->walk($n);
            }
        }
    }
}

$html = <<<'HTML'
    <html><body><div>Content 1</div></body></html>
    <html><body><div>Content 2</div></body></html>
    <html><body><div>Content 3</div></body></html>
HTML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// We'll load the html with multiple body tags here
$oldDom = new DOMExtended;

// We'll recreate the new html here
$newDom = new DOMExtended;
$main = $newDom->childNodes->item(1);
$htmlNode = new DOMElement('html');
$newDom->appendChild($htmlNode);


$oldDom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// extract all the body tags from the old dom
$bodyTags = $oldDom->getElementsByTagName('body');

foreach ($bodyTags as $bodyTag) {
    foreach ($oldDom->walk($bodyTag, true) as $childNode) {
        // recreate the child nodes in the newDom
        $name = $childNode->nodeName;
        if ($name === '#text') { // prevent textnodes
            continue;
        }
        $content = $childNode->nodeValue;
        $newNode = new DOMElement($name, $content);
        // append that node into the newDom
        $htmlNode->appendChild($newNode);
    }
}

// Here's the result
echo $newDom->saveHTML();
```

#### Final Result:

```
<html>
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
    <div>Content 3</div>
</html>
```

To do the recursive walking of the tree part I added a little helper with `DOMExtended` that just does the recursive traversal of the tree through a generator.

Comment: Hi, how is this supposed to remove the <body> tags? It just adds a wrapper.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood your intentions. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I want to save all body contents in one Structure not 3

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do that by putting html codes inside php codes. You can write your code like this :

```
<?php
    echo '<html><body><div>Content</div></body></html>';
    *PHP code to be executed...*
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I'm asking.